# Remove rows after occurence of a specific value the first time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data frame -

| Col_A | Col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 101 | 4 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 102 | 2 |

I want to drop the rows after the first occurrence of "3" from Col_B w.r.t Col_A.

Desired output -

| Col_A | Col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare values by `3`with change order by `iloc` with pass to [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html):

```
df = df[df['Col_B'].iloc[::-1].eq(3).groupby(df['Col_A']).cummax().iloc[::-1]]
print (df)
   Col_A  Col_B
0    101      1
1    101      2
2    101      3
6    102      1
7    102      2
8    102      3
```

Answer (score 0):

A more brute-force type of solution, but has good readability.  In each group, it finds the index of the first occurrence of `3` and takes all rows up to and including the row with the identified index.

```
def remove_rows(df):
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   if df[df['Col_B'] == 3].index.empty:
      return df
   return df.loc[:df[df['Col_B'] == 3].index[0]]

result = df.groupby('Col_A').apply(lambda x: remove_rows(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)

   Col_A  Col_B
0    101      1
1    101      2
2    101      3
3    102      1
4    102      2
5    102      3
```

Comment: ya, now working (in many groups it is slow, but in small data possible solution in my opinion)